# Java dependancy management from a personal dependancy storage/maintenance destination

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I have seen many interesting (and duplicated) questions here about "sharing or using classes between projects".

I see this as quite practical but the proposed solutions I have read about definitely assume certain prerequisites such as:

- shared eclipse workspaces
- projects that can be made as dependencies of oneanother
- common servers such that classpaths can be added with local urls

While likely acceptable solutions, I am looking for an alternative with perhaps greater flexibility and portability.

I am thinking of learning how to use gradle (or maybe maven, I haven't fully committed to one or the other yet).  And from what I understand it may be possible to manage shared classes with one of these dedicated dependency management programs.

Theoretically is this possible?  Can I setup a gradle or maven enabled java project to handle and keep uptodate personal classes on a local server or folder on a portable drive or cloud mirror?

The way I understand dependency management at the moment (on a superficial level, I know the devil is in the details) is that for a configured dependency management enabled project, gradle/maven will handle classpath additions and the actual version specific comparison, retrieval and storage (and maybe even compilation is possible but I don't know about this) of JARS from external sources.

Rather than go through the steps to setup classpaths to jars I have to keep current and compiled myself as proposed in many other answers, I am considering creating a dummy project on a server that I can put generic classes which I could then point numerous individual gradle/maven enabled java projects to use.  (I think most people would be able to keep them as stand alone classes, but I think I might need to keep them in a dummy project to be developed and debugged in context from a main class.  I am somewhat new to java architecture so if the only thing that would make this solution impossible is pointing to a "project" instead of a "library" I can definitely adjust from there. (Assuming I am even applying the concept of the "library appropriately).)

**Other info:**
I would like this to simplify personal dependency using both Netbeans and eclipse IDE's and work cross platform (but Linux and Windows is what I plan to test it on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for portability, and you don't want to compile your java class that you want to share between projects. And you don't mind a local deployment.

The first thing that comes to mind for me is `Git` - I'm not sure if `Gradle`/`Maven` deal in the gritty underworld of the uncompiled. `Composer` will pull in git repos for php, so that got me thinking.

If you're happy with one-way sharing of code among projects, Git has `submodules` that let you do that.

But searching around, apparently there's a git script that goes one step further - [Git Subtrees](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). I also found an intriguing tutorial that will allow you to make changes to common code that you change while working on any particular project that shares it - so obviously be careful - but [check it out](http://mackuba.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/) and see if the Subtrees script might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't see too much sense for dependency management on a "class level". Typically you would bundle your classes in a jar file, which in turn can be considered as a unit with a particular functional range. Such a jar is suitable to be put in a dependency management.

If you are new to such tools, I'd recommend Maven. It is widely used in the Java world and well-integrated in common IDEs. If you stick to its conventions, it will take care of your whole build process from compiling, testing to packaging. There are a lot of plugins available that let you customize practically everything in a simple XML based configuration. You'll have your first project running in 30min and your current project migrated in another 30min.

To share your code with others, you still need a repository where you can upload your Maven-built artifacts to. Depending on your preference there are many possibilities. Shove it to Amazon S3, Maven Central or install your own `Sonatype Nexus` in your private network.